# AWS - SNS - Does use transactional SMS type is carried over to phone carriers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns, verizon

I couldn't find this information on AWS documentation.

Recently we have problem with messages blocked by Verizon marking them as spam.

Question is: Does message type, set in AWS (Transactional or Promotional) could affect the probability of being blocked by phone carrier? Or is it purely used internally by AWS to prioritize delivery?